# How is Smurf Toolkit possible?

Tags: mobile, tools

We've probably all heard about the Smurf Toolkit by now. It's the GCHQ's way of tapping phones revealed by Edward Snowden. So supposedly they can take over your phone (even power it off/on!) by simply sending an encrypted text message. I'm curious as to how it is possible, because while iOS is closed source and there may be a backdoor, Android is fully open-source, so does that mean that there's the same backdoor somewhere in android's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there are "[secret second operating systems](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170874-the-secret-second-operating-system-that-could-make-every-mobile-phone-insecure)" (firmware) installed on mobile devices.

As to how this is possible, various actors around the world [routinely spike equipment and software](https://theintercept.com/2015/09/28/death-athens-rogue-nsa-operation/). This could mean that companies make [secret](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jul/11/microsoft-nsa-collaboration-user-data) [deals](http://www.salon.com/2014/11/16/googles_secret_nsa_alliance_the_terrifying_deals_between_silicon_valley_and_the_security_state/) to install malicious software or equipment without you knowing. In some cases, they even make deals with administrators and programmers, or target them and introduce an APT this way.

One example would be the purposeful introduction of flaws that can be exploited for your own desires. Imagine if you want access to a machine whenever you want. What do you do? Introduce a security flaw *somewhere* in some program or hardware. Let's break this down a bit:

1. You "infect" a machine with a tiny program that purposely allows a buffer overflow exploit to run. You intentionally write bad code for this purpose.
2. Whenever you need to do something, you can exploit the infected program.
3. Send a request, and have the tiny program download extra malware, which then executes.
4. If the downloaded malware is ever detected, the little exploit is still there, allowing potential re-infection, and the true purpose is obscured by something that seems useful.

Purposely introducing security flaws in software to target people is dangerous and immoral, but that is a favorite tool of those who like to harm others electronically.

Comment: The "secret operating systems" mentioned in that article is simply the firmware.  Turns out your laptop has "secret operating systems" for your monitor too.  It's really not secret.

Comment: And your USB devices, etc. It's secret to most people, though. Many don't expect that their devices can easily turn against them.

Comment: A "secret second operating system"...

Comment: Hey, I'm quoting the articles. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! Is it possible to somehow RE this second operating system or detect it?

Comment: You may want to [read this](https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Zaddach-Workshop-on-Embedded-Devices-Security-and-Firmware-Reverse-Engineering-Slides.pdf) document on reverse-engineering embedded devices firmware.

Comment: Thanks! It was a great read and I might try that in near future.